# i want allow user to register only if he crosses 18 years of current date

Tags: angularjs

I am using directive for date. Here is my code.

Controller

```
$scope.ageChecking = function () {

  if($scope.dateOfBirth !== "Invalid Date") {
    var userDate = new Date($scope.dateOfBirth);
    var current_date = new Date();
    var year = current_date.getFullYear();
    var month = current_date.getMonth();
    var day = current_date.getDate();

    var dateDiff = new Date(year + "-" + month + "-" + day);
    var timeDiff = Math.abs(dateDiff.getTime() - userDate.getTime());
    var diffDays = Math.ceil(timeDiff / (1000 * 3600 * 24));
    var noofyears = diffDays / 365;

    if (noofyears < 18) {
      $scope.ageErrorMsg = "Age should be 18 years";
        return false;
      } else {
        $scope.ageErrorMsg = "";
      }
    }
  }
```

Html

```
 <div class="form-group" 
      ng-class="{'has-error':!userRegistrationForm.dateOfBirth.$valid && (!userRegistrationForm.dateOfBirth.$pristine || userRegistrationForm.$submitted)}">
   <label class="control-label">DATE OF BIRTH*</label>
   <div class="clearfix">
     <ng-combo-date-picker name="dateOfBirth" ng-model="dateOfBirth" ng-placeholder="YYYY,MMM,DD" ng-min-date="{{minYear}}" ng-attrs-date='{"class": "form-control"}' ng-attrs-month='{"class": "form-control"}' ng-attrs-year='{"class": "form-control"}' ng-max-date="{{maxYear}}" ng-required="true" ng-year-order="desc" ng-change="ageChecking()"></ng-combo-date-picker>

   </div>
   <div class="help-block" ng-messages="userRegistrationForm.dateOfBirth.$error" ng-if="userRegistrationForm.$submitted || userRegistrationForm.dateOfBirth.$dirty" role="alert">
     <div ng-message="required">Birth Date is required</div>
   </div>
   {{ageErrorMsg}}
 </div>
```

Comment: At the moment it's more like a report of what you're doing rather then a question. Please describe what's wrong with your code

Comment: Hi Alon,   I am checking 18 years old, of current date,  i am trying but not able to achieve the exactly requirement. above is the code.

Comment: What's wrong with `if (new Date().getFullYear() -  $scope.dateOfBirth.getFullYear() < 18) {`?